# How to use "Noto Math" letter alone?

Tags: math-fonts

[image]

There is the upright greek letter like `\uppi` in "Noto Math".

I want use it, but not through `newtxmath` package

I can't find the vf file about "Noto Sans Math RM",
just find "Noto Sans Math MI" (italic math).

How to find "RM" and use it directly? In other word, at MWE after, font `NotoSans-TLF` should be replaced by `Noto Sans Math RM`, this question will be done. Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% \usepackage[notosans]{newtxmath} % not through it

\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OML}{notosansmi}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{bold}{OML}{notosansmi}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbold}{OML}{notosansmi}{b}{it}

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{NotoSans-TLF}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{NotoSans-TLF}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{OT1}{NotoSans-TLF}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}{OT1}{NotoSans-TLF}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet\mathit{bold}{OT1}{NotoSans-TLF}{bx}{it}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\Huge
\[ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{\Big(\dfrac{n}{\mathrm e}\Big)^n\sqrt{2\uppi n}} =1 \]
vs
\[ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{\Big(\dfrac{n}{\mathrm e}\Big)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}} =1 \]
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier in Unicode, with the `range=` option of `unicode-math` package (compile with xelatex\lualatex).

[image: pi]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setmathfont{TexGyrePagellaMath}[Colour=blue]
\setmathfont{Noto Sans Math}[range={"03C0,"1D70B},Colour=red]

\begin{document}
\frame{
\Huge
\[ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{\Big(\dfrac{n}{\symup{e}}\Big)^n\sqrt{2\uppi n}} =1 \]
vs
\[ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{\Big(\dfrac{n}{\mathrm e}\Big)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}} =1 \]
}
\end{document}
```

`\uppi` certainly works and produces an upright pi, but `Noto Sans Math` font is not a math font in terms of Open Type font features.

One solution is to load a placeholder font (here, arbitrarily, TeX Gyre Pagella Math) and load a range from Noto Sans Math.

Or: load everything from Noto Sans Math:

[image: all pi]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setmathfont{TeXGyrePagellaMath}[Colour=blue]
\setmathfont{Noto Sans Math}[range={it/{num,latin}->sfup,
it/{greek}->up,
up/{greek},
up/{num,latin}->sfup,
},
Colour=red]

\begin{document}
\frame{
\Huge
\[ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{\Big(\dfrac{n}{\symup{e}}\Big)^n\sqrt{2\uppi n}} =1 \]
vs
\[ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{\Big(\dfrac{n}{\mathrm e}\Big)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}} =1 \]
}
\end{document}
```

Or any combination of ranges/fonts as desired.

Comment: ok, it's a good way. I found the font include `\uppi`, its name is `NotoSansMathRM`, can we directly to use `\uppi`? Also not through `unicode-math`, using some command like `\DeclareSymbolFont`, `\DeclareMathSymbol`?